# Why is it bad practice to have a click function inside a click function jQuery

Tags: jquery

Why is it bad practice to do this? What problems does this cause to the program?

```
$("foo").click(function(){

    $("another-foo").click(function({

    }));
});
```

Comment: because it might not fire properly all the time. it will be like hit and miss. Why not just create a function and simply call that function inside of your $("foo").click(function(){... ?

Comment: It's because you cannot guarantee the state of events of the page at any given point in its lifetime. Delegated event handlers, or using flags to enable/disable logic are much better approaches

Comment: would it make a difference if I put $("another-foo").click(function()) in a function doThis() and call such function after $("foo").click(function())?

Comment: If you move the code to a function and call that function from within the click handler, that's just semantics and has the same effect.

Comment: That would be better as it's no longer a nested event handler, however the 
 most effective approach depends on the specific use case.

Comment: In addition to the comments above: you also run the risk of adding multiple handlers for the same event.  If I click 'foo' twice, then click 'another-foo', I get 'another-foo''s event handler twice even though I only clicked on it once.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain.

`$(selector).click(function(){........})` just assigns event handler `click` for element `selector` as callback function. In your example, `click` event for element `$("another-foo")` will be assigned only when `click` event is triggered for element `$("foo")`. Untill this, no click events will be handled for element `"another-foo"`. Assigning event handlers is not functions calling! It just set up what function should be called when event fired.